# What the proper way to implement Google Open ID Connect with .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-authentication

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Core Authentication options by following Pluralsight training. In that training they use Azure for Authentication.

I want to use Google. Here is the code to add Google Auth:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            _configuration.Bind("Google", options);
        })
        .AddCookie();

        services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>(); // Dependency Injection for custom service Greeter
        services.AddDbContext<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("OdeToFood")));
        services.AddScoped<IRestaurantData, SqlRestaurantData>(); // scoped to http transaction, dbcontext is not thread safe
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

In appsettings.json I have these defined:

```
{
    "Google": {
        "ClientId": "234092845903-n92krp955lrp46mdf445g5vo0sqp2eks.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "ClientSecret": "bRg1flFud87hfsef89jMKoGW"
    },
    "Greeting":  "Hello from appsettings.json !!",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "OdeToFood": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=OdeToFood;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app, instead of Google Sign In screen I get an error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()

---

InvalidOperationException: Provide Authority, MetadataAddress, Configuration, or ConfigurationManager to OpenIdConnectOptions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions.Validate()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(string scheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, string authenticationScheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**What am I doing wrong?**

ClientID and ClientSecret are defined in Google Developers Console.

Comment: There's built-in integration for this, see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#configure-google-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Add this method in Startup class.

```
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
```

Comment: What is that string "Authentication:Google:ClientId"? Why such weird format, didnt find anywhere why they use this format

Comment: The string points to the secrets.json when you can store ClientId and ClientSecret. You access the secrets.json by right click on the project in solution explorer and click Manage User Secrets.